# flex-direction: column-reverse except the first element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have multiple `article` element which prefer order in reverse, but the first element is a `header` element and i need it to be sticky at top,
how could i reverse all items but the first header element ?

```
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

and

```
<div id="content">
  <header>something</header>

  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `order` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
header {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <header>something</header>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
</div>
```